# Scintilla .NET - Can't find libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, scintilla

I'm trying to get Scintilla .NET working in a C# form I'm making.
I've followed the directions provided in the readme such as adding the Scintilla component to the toolbox, but when I try to drag the component to a C# form I get this following error:
http://tinypic.com/r/152m7wx/4

I've placed the two included dlls (SciLexer.dll, ScintillaNET.dll) in my system32 folder. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

I'm using VS 2008, and Windows 7.

Any ideas why I'd be getting a File not found error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was caused by whatever I used to install the Scintilla stuff. The install was incomplete.

I don't have specifics, but there is another install floating around on the same page you find the first that is complete. I think that should head you in the right direction. Sorry I can be more specific.

If your still stuck, lemme know and I'll try and figure out exactly where I got the files, or maybe I have them lying around somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Is your computer x86 or x64? If it's x64 you need to put the dll's in C:\Windows\SysWOW64
Otherwise do the following: put scilexer.dll in the same directory as scintillanet.dll (note that when you reference scintillanet.dll from VS 2008 it copies it to the debug directory.. so scilexer.dll should also be put in debug.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to "spy" on where it is actually looking for the DLL files.