# How to syntax highlight using scintilla?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, scintilla

How can I syntax highlight using the scintilla. I have *****no***** idea how to use it. I need a code sample that loads scintilla, puts a String[], and runs it in a richtextbox.

Comment: If you are using Scintilla, where does the RTB come in?

Comment: I keep getting an error: http://img121.imageshack.us/content.php?page=done&l=img121/6341/scintilla.png&via=mupload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639073/scintilla-net-cant-find-libraries).

alternatively apparently some file can't be found it seems like an installation issue.

might find more [here](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)